# How can I replace strings with fixed width values?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a file with this format.

```
F 0     0.700    99.000   -99.000 .10   
T 0 TEMPMW1      25.000   500.000 .10  
T 0 TEMPMW2      50.000  5000.000 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10  
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10
```

And I would like to replace the variables with values in a loop, but never exceed 13 characters from left.

The format is basically: `(L1,1X,I1,1X,3(F9.3,1X)`

## Now

`x1 = 370.1164442
x2 = 4651.9392221`

And doing this

```
readLines(paramTemplate) %>% #Reads the template file and replaces the placeholders
  gsub(pattern = "TEMPMW1", replace = format(x1, width=9, justify='none', nsmall=3, digits=3)) %>%
  gsub(pattern = "TEMPMW2", replace = format(x2, width=9, justify='none', nsmall=3, digits=3))
```

is displacing the values

```
F 0     0.700    99.000   -99.000 .10  
T 0   370.116      25.000   500.000 .10 
T 0  4651.939      50.000  5000.000 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10
```

## Expected result

```
F 0     0.700    99.000   -99.000 .10  
T 0   370.116    25.000   500.000 .10 
T 0  4651.939    50.000  5000.000 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A `non-solution` that works:

Make all placeholders of equal size. Keeping it open for other solutions.

```
T 0 TEMPMW1SS    25.000   500.000 .10  
T 0 TEMPMW2SS    50.000  5000.000 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10  
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10
```

Answer (score 0):

An option can be to pad values in a column with `space` such a way that all values of a column has same width as that of maximum character length in that column.

A solution using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate_all(funs(sprintf(paste("%",max(length(as.character(.))),"s"), as.character(.))))

#       V1     V2      V3     V4     V5     V6
# 1  FALSE      0   0.700     99    -99    0.1
# 2   TRUE      0 TEMPMW1     25    500    0.1
# 3   TRUE      0 TEMPMW2     50   5000    0.1
# 4   TRUE      0   0.500   0.05   0.95    0.1
# 5   TRUE      0   0.500   0.05   0.95    0.1
# 6   TRUE      0   0.500   0.05   0.95    0.1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"F 0     0.700    99.000   -99.000 .10   
T 0 TEMPMW1      25.000   500.000 .10  
T 0 TEMPMW2      50.000  5000.000 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10 
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10  
T 0     0.500     0.050     0.950 .10")
```